# Golang/App Engine - securely hashing a user's password

Tags: google-app-engine, hash, go

I have typically used the bcrypt library to do password hashing, but am unable to do so because of the library's use of `syscall`.  I have also tried scrypt.  What other ways are secure, and which would be the best way?

Comment: As far as I'm able to tell the scrypt library at http://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/scrypt/scrypt.go?repo=crypto doesn't use `syscall`.

Comment: Hmm. I tried it, and I get the same error. I think the pbkdf2 lib is using it - If I try that, it dies too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at [go.crypto](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto). It offers support for pbkdf2 and bcrypt. 
Both implementations are purely written in Go and should work on GAE just fine.

The most simple to use is probably bcrypt.
To get the package run:

```
go get golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt
```

Example usage:

```
import "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt" 

func clear(b []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < len(b); i++ {
        b[i] = 0;
    }
}

func Crypt(password []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    defer clear(password)
    return bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(password, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
}

ctext, err := Crypt(pass)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(ctext))
```

The output will be something like this:

```
$2a$10$sylGijT5CIJZ9ViJsxZOS.IB2tOtJ40hf82eFbTwq87iVAOb5GL8e
```

If you want simply the hash, use pbkdf2. Example:

```
import "golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2"

func HashPassword(password, salt []byte) []byte {
    defer clear(password)
    return pbkdf2.Key(password, salt, 4096, sha256.Size, sha256.New)
}

pass := []byte("foo")
salt := []byte("bar")

fmt.Printf("%x\n", HashPassword(pass, salt))
```

Comment: @HelinWang It's not but I like to overwrite the memory where the plain text password was kept.

Comment: A good addition could be that Mercurial is needed to go get that lib, to install it on ubuntu for example you need to do sudo apt-get install mercurial which solved it for me. But if you are using another system, please check this page: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Download

Comment: 'brew install mercurial' did the same for me on a Mac. I didn't sudo and it seems to be OK.

Comment: @NimrodShory What SSH package? Can you elaborate? Maybe ask a new question.

Comment: FYI -- this implementation has moved.  New docs: http://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt